# Is the operator $Tf = f(\sqrt{x})$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the operator $$f\to Tf = f(\sqrt{x}). $$ How do I show whether it is continuous or not for $C[0,1]$ (uniform norm) and $L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: Hint for the first of those: if you know a bound on the values of $f$, can you find a bound on the values of $Tf$?

Comment: Hint.-T is continuous at $f=0$. This is enough to prove T is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that $T$ is linear: $T(\alpha f+ \beta g)=\alpha Tf+ \beta Tg$.

1) As regards $C[0,1]$,  by letting $x=t^2$, 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|(Tf)(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(\sqrt{x})|=
\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|.$$

2) On the other hand, in $L^2[0,1]$, again by letting $x=t^2$,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1((Tf)(x))^2 dx=\int_0^1(f(\sqrt{x}))^2 dx=
\int_0^1(f(t))^2 2t dt\leq 2\int_0^1(f(t))^2 dt.
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I tried to show boundedness first.

Comment: @blux Look at my answer and let $g=0$.

Comment: Yes, then it holds but why does your equalities hold in the first place? Only a matter of function domain/range?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt{x}$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$.

Comment: Is it a better way of showing continuous to have the $Tf-Tg$ and then putting g to 0? Compared to only start with $\sup | Tf | $

Comment: My hint is related to the continuity question. Anyway, here we are in a normed vector space and $T$ is linear, so you may use $f$ only and write $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|(Tf)(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(\sqrt{x})|=
\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75655/discussion-between-blux-and-robert-z).